# Jest cli testPathIgnorePatterns with jest.config.js results in No tests found

Tags: jestjs

I want to run jest combining cli and jest.config.js, so I can use the same config but with minor changes at run time

```
jest --config=jest.config.js
```

Results in

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 163 passed, 164 total
Tests:       8 skipped, 1685 passed, 1693 total
Snapshots:   87 passed, 87 total
Time:        34.719s, estimated 44s
```

While

```
jest --config=jest.config.js --testPathIgnorePatterns=[ignore]
```

Results in

```
752 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 164 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [ignore] - 0 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

If I modify the config

```
modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
'<rootDir>/src/.*/__mocks__',
'<rootDir>/node_modules',
'<rootDir>/.*/ignore',
],
```

Results in

```
Test Suites: 163 passed, 163 total
Tests:       8 skipped, 1685 passed, 1693 total
Snapshots:   87 passed, 87 total
Time:        31.417s
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--testpathignorepatternsarray) states that testPathIgnorePatterns is an array. Arrays in shell are comma or space separated.

This works:

```
jest --config=jest.config.js --testPathIgnorePatterns=ignore
```

As would:

```
jest --config=jest.config.js --testPathIgnorePatterns=ignore,ignoreThisAsWell
```

Comment: Context switching from JS to shell sometimes does my head in :(

Comment: Running with 2 parameters (like --testPathIgnorePatterns=ignore,ignoreThisAsWell) didn't work here

Answer (score 0):

As per @[Tiago Gouvêa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448292/tiago-gouv%c3%aaa)'s comment on [mummybot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158815/mummybot)'s answer, comma separated doesn't work everywhere.

For me, space separated and doubling the argument both work (I suspect the latter might be more consistently supported).

```
jest --config=jest.config.js --testPathIgnorePatterns=ignore --testPathIgnorePatterns=ignoreThisAsWell
```